Non-stateful media query in CSS?
I'm trying to hide and reveal a sidebar based on the client screen width using two respective animations (hide-sidebar and reveal-sidebar). To achieve this functionality I'm employing a media query:
@media screen and (max-width: [max-width]) {
    #sidebar {
      animation-name: hide-sidebar;
    }
}

Then, the sidebar's rules look like this:
#sidebar {
    ...

    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

    animation-name: reveal-sidebar;
}

The idea is of course that the media query changes the animation-name property depending on the client width, and the respective animation plays once every time that happens.
However, the animation plays once on page load as well, which I of course do not want. It doesn't really impact functionality, but it looks weird and unprofessional.
To my knowledge, media queries in CSS are entirely stateful, so there's no avail in trying to tamper with it. Or is there?
Is there a pure CSS fix for my current approach at all or should I change it altogether?
Is there a pure CSS fix at all? I'm trying to avoid using scripting for this if possible.

Did you try to also set the width/position of your sidebar when changing the animation? The animation should do nothing, if the value is already the final animation value.

@jonas Still does something, since there are other stops within the keyframes, such as at 95%.


Is there a pure CSS fix at all? I'm trying to avoid using scripting for this if possible.

There is a pure CSS approach, but I'd suggest not using animation at all and using transition instead.

Working Example:


.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(191, 0, 0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}

@media screen and (width < 960px) {
 .sidebar {
    transform: translateX(180px);
  }
}
<aside class="sidebar"></aside>




Right, I realize I ought to figure out something simpler than animation. Thank you!
